# Bifurcation diagram of $\frac{dx}{dt} = r - \cos(x)$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, bifurcation

I plotted several vector fields for different values of $r$, specifically:
$$r = 1$$
This gave me half-stable fixed points at $2k\pi, k \in \mathbb{Z}$.
$$r > 1$$
No fixed points.
$$-1<r < 1$$
Infinitely many fixed points which change from stable to unstable
$$r = -1$$
Half-stable fixed points at $(2k+1)\pi, k\in\mathbb{Z}.$
$$r < -1$$
No fixed points.

When attempting to plot the bifurcation diagram I get $x^* = \arccos(r)$, do I plot this on a restricted domain or an infinite domain?

How do I determine which values of $r$ give bifurcations as there are infinitely many of them, essentially I have no idea how to label the fixed points on the bifurcation diagram.

Comment: Hint: This is an autonomous system of the form $\frac{dx}{dt}=f(x)$. To figure out the stability, calculate $f'(x)$, plug in the fixed points and note that stability occurs when $f'(x)<0$...

Comment: @Moo Yeah, I managed to find a solution to the problem online.

Comment: @Moo It's an online university resource, I might be able to send a screenshot but I dont know how to give it to you

Answer (score 1):

This is a non-generic situation, these are usually not named. Add some perturbation like
$$
x=r-\cos(x)+\varepsilon\sin(\sqrt2 x)
$$
to get all those fold-bifurcations isolated, one bifurcation per bifurcation point.
\begin{align}
0&=f_r(x)=r-\cos(x)+\varepsilon\sin(\sqrt2 x)\\
0&=f_r'(x)=\sin(x)+ε\sqrt2\cos(\sqrt2 x)
\end{align}
From the second equation $x_n\approx n\pi$ and iterating to get the next perturbation terms
$$
x_n\approx n\pi-ε(-1)^n\sqrt2\cos(\sqrt2 n\pi)
$$
and thus from the first equation
$$
r_n\approx\cos(x_n)-ε\sin(\sqrt2 x_n)
=(-1)^n(1+ε^2\cos^2(\sqrt2 n\pi))
-ε\sin(\sqrt2 n\pi)+O(ε^3)
$$
which in general will not be equal for different values of $n$.